# Animate.css First Time

Tags: css, animation, animate.css

Hi i am using the animate.css first time. I just download the animate.css file add in  my project and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYf9t.png) a animation. the animation is in the middle of my page content which view after scroll down now the problem is when i refresh the page the animation is working but  when i scroll down to see the animation i can not see it because it is done before i scroll down.what i have to do control is to animate only when i scroll down.

Comment: I usually combines [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) with `animate.css`, which helps you on on-scroll animation and delaying. Maybe you can give it a try :).

Comment: Thanks Its working